# Debian Bullseye Custom install on VPS

Tags: debian, package-management, nftables

I have an idea-question. There is a clean install of Bullseye on a VPS. This distro has new Bind, new Dovecot, new Apache, etc. If I back it up and then re-install it EXCLUDING new Bind, new Dovecot and all the other pre-installed packages that I do not need and then install slighlty older versions of Bind, Dovecot and so on, will that potentially work or will that create a mess of dependencies hell?

Can I also install just bare metals of Bullseye without Apparmor, without NFtables and some other "parts" that I do not need and do not like? How? By the way, are NFtables replacable? I'd like to stick to normal iptables.

Would really appreciate any pointers, advice, suggestions at all. Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to install older software, and yes, the results might be unexpected.

If you choose to add third party repositories with older software you'll probably benefit from setting repository pinning in `/etc/apt/preferences.d/` so the you'll only replace the software you intended to replace.

Apt pinning syntax is explained in `man 5 apt_preferences` and https://wiki.debian.org/AptConfiguration.

Apparmor can be disabled by `systemctl disable apparmor.service` or
`systemctl mask apparmor.service`.

You may use iptables utilities to configure nftables. It is also still possible to purge nftables and use legacy iptables and netfilter-persistent. It is still advised to get used used to nftables since iptables will probably be removed from future releases.

Answer (score 1):

Whether it will create a dependency hell depends on where you're getting packages with old versions of bind/dovecot/...
If you have a repository that provides the old versions you want for Bullseye it should just work.

But installing old software sounds like a recipe for security problems.